# Parameter passed to javascript is not accepted

Tags: javascript

I have to load file xyz.html into a `<div>` of file abc.html. This `<div>` is an overlay, which I need to load on clicking of a link. When I am trying to send the path of xyz.html as a paramter, then the document is not loaded.

```
function load_home(param)
{
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
        '<object type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" data=param></object>';
}
```

But when I directly put the path in data attribute, then it's working fine:

```
function load_home(param)
{
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
        '<object type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" data = "xyz.html"></object>';
}
```

Even this is not working, which is very strange:

```
function load_home(param)
{
    var param = "xyz.xml";
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
        '<object type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" data=param ></object>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript thinks your `param` is part of the String and not the variable. You need to pull `param` out of the String an concatenate all of the Strings using the `+`operator.
Take a look at this:

```
function load_home(param)
{
var param = "xyz.xml";
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
    '<object type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" data="' + param + '" ></object>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have one more query-

Comment: I have a list which is populated on click of previous button, something like "1"[one] is the root and "2"[two] is its child, so when "1" is clicked "2"[two] will be opened, and "3"[three] is child of "2"[two] which will get opened once "2" is clicked.. this is the series.. Here "1", "2" and "3" are the buttons, and [one], [two] and [three] are the hyperlinks. Now, I need to call the overlay method on click of [two] and [three] and so on... but in this case when I click on 1, 2[two] gets populated..

Comment: but when I click [two] the overlay should open and data should be populated in overlay. But, data is not shown in overlay unless I click on "3" and [three] is not clicked. Once [three] is clicked and overlay displays the expected content, [two] will work as expected. I m not sure what is the dependency. How can I remove this?

Comment: [two] should populate the content at the first time only, it should not be dependent on [three] or "3". Please give me the solution.